# How do I create an array, dynamic in one dimension yet static in others? C

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, dynamic-arrays

Here is my current attempt however when I try to assign a double to one element I am told that the "subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector". Can anyone point me in the right direction (pun intended).

```
int i;
double x[2];
for(i=0;i<2;i++){
double *x[i];
x[i] = (double*) malloc(10000*sizeof(double));
}
```

Comment: do you even indent bro

Answer (score 2):

Make a static array of pointers:

```
int i;
double *x[2];
for(i=0;i<2;i++){
    x[i] = malloc(10000*sizeof(double));
}
```

And proceed as you are ([without casting the result of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)).

Comment: Well that was easier than expected, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Write the following way

```
int i;
double *x[2];
for(i=0;i<2;i++){
    x[i] = (double*) malloc(10000*sizeof(double));
}
```

Or you could even write provided that the array itself has automatic storage duration.

```
double *x[2] = { malloc(10000*sizeof(double)), malloc(10000*sizeof(double)) };
```